# Django query by related object with calculated value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have this Class structure:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    CHOICE_1 = 'example-1'
    CHOICE_2 = 'example-2'
    CHOICE_3 = 'example-3'
    EXAMPLE_CHOICES = [
        (CHOICE_1, 'Example 1'),
        (CHOICE_2, 'Example 2'),
        (CHOICE_3, 'Example 3')
    ]
    
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EXAMPLE_CHOICES)
    important = models.BooleanField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="child")
```

I need to get all **A** objects that have related **B** objects filter by:

1. At least one child have **important=True**
2. At least one child have **CHOICES_1 or CHOICE_2** in choice attr.

So far the query would be:

```
A.objects.filter(child__important=True, child__choice__in=[CHOICE_1, CHOICE_2])
```

**HERE IT COMES THE QUESTION**

Also, I need to get an extra calculated field which value should be:

- If A has only CHOICE_1 childs --> **calculated value = "Example 1 only"**
- elif A has only CHOICE_2 childs --> **calculated value = "Example 2 only"**
- elif A has childs, some CHOICE_1 and some CHOICE_2 --> **calculated value = "Both"**

Requirements:

- Django 2.2
- Using single query

Comment: Is your aim to achieve this with a single query i.e. using some form of [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/)? Depending on how the extra calculated field is used, it could simply be a `@property` of model `A`.

Comment: @elyas yes. I forgot to mention I need everything in only one query